# Constructing a Random Variable From a Law

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a polish space and let $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(X,\mathcal{B}(X))$.  How can we construct an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued random element with law $\mu$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot comment, I have to write this as an answer:

the law of a random variable is the measure induced by it on the target space. You can not use it to induce a measure on the original measure space(here is $\mu$). You need to find a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be the candidate.

And I am not sure about the criteria for this to work, waiting for others to solve it :)

One thing I am sure is that it depends on the topology on $X$. If the topology is trivial with all open sets $\{\emptyset,X\}$, then you cannot define a random variable inducing law on $\mathbb{R}^n$ not concentrating on one single value.